# Python/psycopg2 Error in SELECT WHERE IN

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I've tried to use postgres from python with psycopg2 (version 2.7.1) but just unable to do so. 
I need to retrieve specific id's from the table so I'm trying to use the IN statement

```
dbase=# select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

But when trying with Python, and after reviewing related questions I've como up with this attempts.

If I try this:

```
query = '''
...:         SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
...: '''
```

I get:

```
 In [71]: cursor.execute(query)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    InternalError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-71-2e97bea5433e> in <module>()
    ----> 1 cursor.execute(query)

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

If instead I try using a variable to keep the wanted id's:

```
In [87]: query = '''
    ...:         SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN %s
    ...: '''

In [88]: datos = "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)"

In [89]: cursor.execute(query,(datos,))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-4be5e55885c7> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.execute(query,(datos,))

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)'"
LINE 2:         SELECT * FROM demanda WHERE id IN '(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)'
```

The formatted query seems to be closer to what I want but I don't understand why the single apostrophes are being placed, since psql doesn't recognized them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make `datos` a tuple:

```
datos = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
InternalError: current transaction is aborted
```

is not caused by your statement, but from a previous error that left the connection in error state.

Your first attempt was right, the second is wrong. This should work:

```
>>> query = '''SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN %s'''
>>> datos = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
>>> cursor.execute(query, (datos,))
```

Note that if the tuple is empty this will give an SQL error (not psycopg fault). Using a list and the `ANY` operator is a more robust solution:

```
>>> query = '''SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = any (%s)'''
>>> datos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> cursor.execute(query, (datos,))
```